# Python 3.X, can't get a background image behind my buttons

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to apply an image to the background. With my buttons to be on top of given image (with their pictures). I attempted Canvas, PIL, but either of them aren't working or the image comes over everything. Any ideas? (AGAIN sorry for the orientation of my code).

```
from tkinter import *
import os
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# create the main window and title



app = Tk()
app.title("Virtual Receptionist")

app.geometry("300x300")
app.configure(background="black")

# background images




label1 = Label(app, text="Please select a name from the Directory or press 
    Deliveries")
label1.place(x= 64, y = 22, height=135, width=20)

mainwindow = app


"""Define any items that will be utilized when the button(s) are pressed (Close Window, Bat files for calling, any additional options)"""


# Testing area



# closed the window commandlet#

    def closewindow():
        exit()



# call numbers listed in individual bat files for use when button is pressed (each bat will have it own number or extension)

def callOffice():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")
def callOffice1():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")
def callOffice2():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")
def callOffice3():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")
def callOffice4():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")
def callOffice5():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")
def callOffice6():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")
def callOffice7():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")
def callOffice8():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")
def callOffice9():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")
def callOffice10():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")
def callOffice11():
    os.system("c:/netis/phone/callfile.bat")


# images for the pictures that display over the buttons listed below

photo1=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg1.png")
photo2=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg2.png")
photo3=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg3.png")
photo4=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg4.png")
photo5=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg5.png")
photo6=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg6.png")
photo7=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg7.png")
photo8=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg8.png")
photo9=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg9.png")
photo10=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg10.png")
photo11=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg11.png")
photo12=PhotoImage(file="image folder/customerimg12.png")
photoc=PhotoImage(file="image folder/close.png")



# creating the button schema for the extensions

button1 = Button(mainwindow,  text="Close Window", command=closewindow,  
    image=photoc, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button2 = Button(mainwindow,  text="client name1", command=callOffice, 
    image=photo1, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button3 = Button(mainwindow, text="client name2", command=callOffice1, 
    image=photo2, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button4 = Button(mainwindow, text="client name3", command=callOffice2, 
    image=photo3, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button5 = Button(mainwindow, text="client name4", command=callOffice3, 
    image=photo4, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button6 = Button(mainwindow, text="client name5", command=callOffice4, 
    image=photo5, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button7 = Button(mainwindow, text="client name6", command=callOffice5, 
    image=photo6, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button8 = Button(mainwindow, text="client name7", command=callOffice6, 
    image=photo7, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button9 = Button(mainwindow, text="client name8", command=callOffice7, 
    image=photo8, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button10 = Button(mainwindow, text="client name9", command=callOffice8, 
    image=photo9, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button11 = Button(mainwindow, text="client name10", command=callOffice9, 
    image=photo10, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button12 = Button(mainwindow, text="client name11", command=callOffice10, 
    image=photo11, bg='Dark Slate Gray')
button13 = Button(mainwindow, text="client name12", command=callOffice11, 
    image=photo12, bg='Dark Slate Gray')



#Configs for the buttons Size(s):#

button1.config(image=photoc, width="155", height="150")
button2.config(image=photo1, width="155", height="150")
button3.config(image=photo2, width="155", height="150")
button4.config(image=photo3, width="155", height="150")
button5.config(image=photo4, width="155", height="150")
button6.config(image=photo5, width="155", height="150")
button7.config(image=photo6, width="155", height="150")
button8.config(image=photo7, width="155", height="150")
button9.config(image=photo8, width="155", height="150")
button10.config(image=photo9, width="155", height="150")
button11.config(image=photo10, width="155", height="150")
button12.config(image=photo11, width="155", height="150")
button13.config(image=photo12, width="155", height="150")


# Button Orentation within the window itself (calling to grid func)#

button1.grid(row=0, column=0)
button2.grid(row=2, column=4)
button3.grid(row=2, column=5)
button4.grid(row=2, column=6)
button5.grid(row=2, column=7)
button6.grid(row=2, column=8)
button7.grid(row=2, column=9)
button8.grid(row=4, column=4)
button9.grid(row=4, column=5)
button10.grid(row=4, column=6)
button11.grid(row=4, column=7)
button12.grid(row=4, column=8)
button13.grid(row=4, column=9)

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Don't be sorry about your code. _Fix your code_. If you're not willing to spend just a few minutes properly formatting your question, why would you expect strangers to spend time trying to  understand it? Also, please read and follow the advice here: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If your problem is with a button and a background image, you don't need 13 buttons to illustrate the problem when one will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see the background text adjust the numbers in the line:

```
label1.place(x= 64, y = 22, height=135, width=20)
```

to numbers making the text no more hidden behind the button:

```
label1.place(x=200, y=22, height=20, width=400)
```

Another option is to use a large background image, so that you can see in any case the image behind the buttons:

```
mainwindow = app

filename = PhotoImage(file="/path/To/Background/image.png")
background_label = Label(app, image=filename)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
```

For more about what is going on behind the scenes in tkinter put in the search box here on stackoverflow.com the terms "tkinter background image" - there is a lot of valuable information available on this subject.

Comment: so, just move the snippet up higher with the testing area in this, update a new jpg file and it worked, you fn ROCK!, just for noted this is a lay over for a softphone, it calls to a bat with the exe file of the software and a number (runs under cmd), its design was to make a virtual receptionist system on a touch screen, thank you again@Claudio!!!!

Answer (score 0):

```
app.geometry("")
master.title("Welcome page")
 = PhotoImage(file = "lunch.png")
my_label = Label(master, image= )
my_label.place(x = 0, y = 0, relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)
```

before the buttons list.